# Smartphone and desktop app communication technology and cross platform Framework

Tags: android, ios, linux, cross-platform

Guys I need you to lead me on the right way. I need to develop a desktop application that communicates with multiple devices (smart phones and tablets). This Desktop application has to run on a Linux system and can use only a local network (no Internet). Devices are sending and receiving data from the desktop application. First problem is which technology should I use to connect smart phones with desktop app?

- Bluetooth. If I use Bluetooth is there a problem as one Bluetooth host can connect max 7 clients (I need to connect up to 12 devices). I could use than two Bluetooth modules. Then also, if someone has a smart watch, his phone can’t be connected with his smart watch and the desktop app at the same time.
- NFC. The problem here is that not all smart devices are NFC compatible.
- Wi-Fi Hotspot. I am considering using Wi-Fi network as a connection, but I am not sure because of security issues.
- What do you recommend? Do you know any other possibility?

The second problem is that I don’t know which Framework and Tools should I use to develop the desktop app (Linux) and for the smart phone and tablet apps (iOS and Android). Should I use Qt with C++ or JavaFX for the desktop app? I was also researching other cross platform Frameworks (https://www.slant.co/topics/983/~best-cross-platform-gui-toolkits and https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/frameworks-tools-build-cross-platform-desktop-apps/) but some could be costly as I am not a professional programmer and do this stuff in my free time. What do you recommend?
For smart phone app, I am considering to use Unity. Any better choice?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Personally the way I would do it is to put a database in between, have the device upload data to the database and have you're desktop application read the database.

I recommend electron personally for developing the app, but this will be largely driven by your skill set. Electron is primarily HTML, CSS and Javascript (you can use node to talk to database). The advantage of electron is it cross platform compatible.